# ReactJS: change input field border color for particular element ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having hard time to change input field border color for selected elements based on theirs IDs.

I have tried vanilla JavaScript like

```
       fetch("/login?"+query, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            credentials: "include"
        }).then(response => {
            status = response.status;
            return response.json()
        }).then(data => {
            if (status==200) {
                //log in
            }
            else {
                if (status==404) {
                  document.getElementById('user').style.border('1px solid red');
                  document.getElementById('password').style.border('1px solid red');
                }
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            setErrors({
                systemErr: err
            });
        })
```

but what failed with an error that not able to render modified child element.

Also I have styles set for required fields indications as

`style={getStyles(touched, props.errors, 'password')}`

then

```
function getStyles (touched, error, fieldName) {
    if (errors[fieldName] && touched[fieldName]) {
        return {
            border: '1px solid red'
        }
    }
};
```

and that works fine but what I need to have get a border when the API will not return anything as well. Side note - I'm using Formik with Yup for validation of required fields.

Any tips on that?

Comment: I am not sure, why your mixing `React` and direct `DOM` manipulation.

You can easily manage API failure/success with `reudx` state and based on that prop you can add new class to input.

Comment: @SandipNirmal I'm new to Redux and just started to use it in that login page but just to store data after the log in. Didn't thought to have that for the API failure/success. Can you point me to some examples? Thanks!

Comment: You can have look at this https://github.com/SandipNirmal/react-app-boilerplate. This is something I created long back. You can have look at `loginReducer`. You should get idea.

**BTW** repo needs some updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add states to the components and just pass them to component styles.

Comment: I have done something similar to indicate required fields and that works. I have updated OP with that part of the code

Comment: Well. That answer pointed me to right direction. I have updated a state to have both required fields at that case.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your lines with this code.

```
 document.getElementById('user').style.border = '1px solid red';
 document.getElementById('password').style.border ='1px solid red';
```

You are calling border as a function but its a property.

Comment: Still the same problem: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Are you calling this function in `componentDidMount`  ?

Comment: Do you have the full React Component code? Please share.

Comment: @PrabhatKumar No, I don't - I have it in the promise at presented in the OP

Comment: @Ranjith is too big and only fails on presented code above. Thought it will be simple to change borders when fetch to the API found nothing.

Comment: Can you please create a sandbox link of your code and share ?